# How to use concat reduce and find together in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use concat reduce and filter together in JS. I found a exercise where I can use the same three methods. And I found one solution also. But I couldn't get completely how that works. I have debugged by keeping breakpoints and I understood some parts of it but not completely. Could anyone help me to make understand how the following logic works? Thanks in advance.

```
    var item1 = [
        {"id":1,"b":"first"},
        {"id":2,"b":"second"}
        ];
        
    var item2 = [
        {"id":3,"b":"third", "c":true},
        {"id":1,"b":"fourth", "c":true}, 
        {"id":2,"b":"fivth", "c":true},
        {"id":4,"b":"frr", "c":true}
        ];
        
    var res = item1.concat(item2).reduce((aggr, el)=>{
        // console.log("aggr", aggr)
        if(!aggr.find(item2=>item2.id==el.id))
            return [...aggr, el];
        else
            return aggr
    },[])
```

1. `item1.concat(item2)` = I understand that I am concating item1 and
   item2.
2. `.reduce` = I am aware that reduce will accept 2 params one is
   accumulator and another one is currentvalue, here aggr is acc and el is current value.
3. I am not getting the logic of !aggr inside if. What is that meaning of !aggr inside find
   I am getting they are checking for same ID but before that !aggr is confusing.

Comment: basically they are checking if the current element "el" is in the accumulator variable which is an array, if it is then it skips, otherwise it adds it to the array. It basically removes duplicates that might exist from merging the arrays.

Comment: Give an example of what the result actually looks like -- better yet post code as a [mcve]. BTW `.filter()` isn't used `.find()` is.

Comment: aggr.find returns the first element which satisfies the condition. if nothing found it returns undefined. !aggr.find() will be true when find returns undefined which means that element not found inside array so they are adding it inside if block.

Answer (score 0):

In short, after concatenating the two arrays, it reduces/removes the items from the concatenated array with the same id of the item2 array.

FYI, in every iteration aggr consists of the previous iteration value returned by the reduce method, and el consists of the current value of the concatenated array.

*`aggr.find(item2=>item2.id==el.id)`* returns the first element from the aggr which has the same id as el. if nothing is found it returns undefined. *`!aggr.find()`* will be true when finding returns undefined.

When the if the condition is true it is adding the el element with aggr and returns the value with *`return [...aggr, el]`* statement. Else it is only returning the aggr.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any more confusion!